# How to use 1 aura component for multiple buttons

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-button

I want to build 1 aura:component for both New, Edit, and Clone buttons. How can I recognize which one is triggering this component when execute? Please help
[image]

Comment: My understanding is that the component isn't actually aware of the action that it is overriding, so this might not be possible. However, you could create a generic component which is in turn housed by the three specific ones for Clone, Edit and New.